# Wordpress + Woocommerce: hide unavailable variations when there are 2 attributes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce

I have a variable product in WordPress + WooCommerce and it has 2 attributes: color and size.

I'd like that when I select one of these 2 attributes, the unavailable variations with the second attribute will be automatically hidden (or unselectable) from the attribute select menu.

Is it possible? How can I achieve that?

I haven't found any plugin that can do that. I'm trying to figure out what part of code to edit, but it's quite a difficult task...

Comment: WooCommerce automatically does that. If you've selected one attributes from 1st drop down menu, it'll automatically remove unavailable variation's attribute from second dropdown. Secondly, if you want to hide a variation, you can empty its price. WooCommerce automatically removes it from dropdown menu

Comment: Mmmm, nope... maybe is a problem with the theme I'm using? (The Retailer) I don't think so. I already checked the "Hide out of stock items from the catalog" option, but it hides only the products from the catalog when there are no variations in stock. Is there any other setting I should use?

Comment: UPDATE: with just one attribute it works properly, but I still have a problem when I have 2 attributes..

Comment: Are you referring "unavailable variations" with stock of that variation. That means, if a particular variations runs out of stock, it should be disabled in attribute select menu?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to variations of a product that are out of stock. If you'll have a look at [this page](http://www.pandaviamilano.it/shop/brand-diadora/diadora-equipe-l-perf-sw/) (it's in italian, but probably you can understand anyway) you can see 2 attributes. It let you select "Colore: Marrone/Bianco" and "Taglia: 40 EU..", but then it gives an "out of stock" message because the stock for that variation is 0. I'd like that if you select "Marrone/Bianco" the out of stock combinations with "Taglia" will be automatically hidden/disabled from the dropdown menu below. Is it possible?

Comment: I need that feature too. Most major online stores have it, WooCommerce doesn't and it's REALLY annoying. I found a solution that greys out unavailable variations but only when there's one attribute (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879413/greying-out-out-of-stock-product-variations-woocommerce). However when there are several attributes - a pretty common scenario - then WooCommerce is just incapable of handling it professionally. And based on the dev team attitude towards this problem my guess is it won't change.

Comment: I have the same issue, with 3 attributes and different combinations of all three. I want to hide the disabled variations. :(

Answer (score 2):

I ran into your (old) question as i had it too. This is a working solution.
Change 'return 10' to a number higher than your total amount of variations.

Add it to your function.php file:

```
function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) {
    return 10;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```