# Greying out out of stock products fails on single option products (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this code found here: [Greying out out-of-stock product variations (WooCommerce)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29879413/greying-out-out-of-stock-product-variations-woocommerce)

More discussion here:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/5661

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
    return false;

return true;
```

}

It seem to work well on products that have 2 options with a handful of values. Such as this one: https://candlsaddles.com/shop/footwear/macie-bean-never-promised-you-a-rose-garden-snip-toe-boots-m8012/

It doesn't seem to work in the following scenarios:

Products that only use 1 option and a handful of values such as sizes. Such as this one:
https://candlsaddles.com/shop/footwear/kids-anderson-bean-chocolate-impostrich-boots-hpy7083/

Products that have many options and values such as this one with more than 25 Sizes and 15 Widths
https://candlsaddles.com/shop/footwear/womens-anderson-bean-antique-saddle-full-quill-ostrich-1079a/

Does anyone have any input on what may be causing this?
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't replicate this issue, seems to work for all scenarios for me with Woo 3.3.4

Comment: That's interesting. Guess I should have added a few more details. I'm running WC 3.3.5 and WP 4.9.5 hosted on WP Engine.

The two scenarios that don't work that I mentioned above I'll add some more details on.

Products with 1 option and around 40 values half of which should be "out of stock"

Products with 2 options, the first having around 22 values, the second having around 10 values. This makes for a total of 210 Possible combinations.

Neither of these scenarios work. But a product with 2 options, the first having around around 22 values and the second having only 1 value works.

Comment: Could be a plugin or theme issue....  Good idea to try and deactivate some plugins or try with a different theme to see if it makes a difference.